# Using Bootstrap Badges Within @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'd like to create a basic bootstrap [button with a badge](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges) using Razor @Html.ActionLink syntax. I tried the following:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Html.Raw("<span class=\"badge\">42</span>")+"System Message Here", "Index", "Message", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Which results in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrIEn.png). I would like to see the badge icon instead of the HTML. What is the correct syntax? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `Url.Action` instead, like so:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Message")" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="badge">42</span> System Message Here
</a>
```

Comment: @Bannerman, If you use this regularly, might be a good idea to create a custom html helper - say `@Html.BootstrapBadgeLink(linkText, action, controller)` - that generates this html for you.

Comment: @Stephen great suggestion. I just finished writing it and will use it throughout my code.